# Download on USB Drive

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu on my USB drive. A screen called NTI Media Maker popped up asking me how I wanted to burn the disk. What should I do?

Comment: don't copy the Ubuntu iso file to usb.Just create a bootable ubuntu usb through unetbootin software.

Comment: As the above comment says, don't just copy the files, see [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for installing from a USB on Windows:

### USB installer - Windows

Download [Pendrive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), install it and open it.

Select Ubuntu Desktop Edition, for the version you downloaded:
[image]

Select <kbd>Browse</kbd>:

[image]

Select the `iso` image. Go back to the PendriveLinux window, and then select your USB drive. **Make sure that you have no data on it you want, as it will probably be wiped.** The USB drive also needs to be larger than the image file.

Press <kbd>Create</kbd>

---

### USB installer - Mac

For Mac, instructions are available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Comment: How to boot an Alpha image this way?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - Aslong as it is an ISO file, it should work. For 14.04 Trusty Tahr, which I think you are referring to, see [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) for the iso files ;-). ***Other users** - Note this is still in Alpha, so will not be fully supported yet, it will have bugs, and questions on it here for [some reasons](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate) are not tolerated.*